# javascript function move to webworker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I have function:

```
function addModel() {

    var values = new Array();
    var $input = $('input[type=\'text\']');
    var error = 0;
    $input.each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('double-error');
        var that = this;
        if (that.value!='') {
            values[that.value] = 0;
            $('input[type=\'text\']').each(function() {
                if (this.value == that.value) {
                    values[that.value]++;
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $input.each(function(key) {
        if (values[this.value]>1) {
            //error++;
        var name = this.value;
        var product_model = $(this).parent().parent().find('.product-model').text();
        var m = product_model.toLowerCase().areplace(search,replace);
     $(this).parent().find('input[type=\'text\']').val(name + '-' + m);

        }

    }); 


    return error <= 0; //return error > 0 ? false : true;
}
```

where are a lot of inputs to recheck... up to 50000. Usually are about 5000 to 20000 inputs. Of course browsers are freezing... How to move this function to web-worker and call it to get data back and fill form type="text"

thank you in advance.

Comment: A web worker won't have access to the DOM. Why on earth would there be 50,000 text fields on a single page?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp

Comment: *"where are a lot of entries to recheck"* What do you mean by "entries"? Surely not text fields? If so, I couldn't imagine the browser even getting to the point of running your code above...

Comment: This is the web shop. Here are the part of the script function to add SEO keywords for the products. Products can be up to 50000. Usually are about 5000 to 20000 products. :)

Comment: You need to revisit the fundamental design. Even 5k `input` elements is far, far too many (and I guarantee you they are not helping your SEO).

Answer (score 0):

Web workers don't have direct access to the DOM. So to do this, you'd need to gather the values of all 5-50k `input`s into an array or similar, and then send that to the web worker (via `postMessage`) for processing, and have the web worker do the relevant processing and post the result back, and then use that result to update the `input`s. See any web worker tutorial for the details of launching the worker and passing messages back and forth (and/or see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22833230/157247)).

Even just gathering up the values of the inputs and posting them to the web worker is going to take significant time on the main UI thread, though, as is accepting the result from the worker and updating the `input`s; even 5k `input`s is just far, far too many for a web page.

Answer (score 0):

If maintaining browser responsiveness is the issue, then releasing the main thread periodically will allow the browser to process user input and DOM events.  The key to this approach is to find ways to process the inputs in smaller batches.  For example:

```
var INTERVAL = 10; // ms
var intervalId = setInterval((function () {
  var values = [];
  var $input = $('input[type=\'text\']');
  var index;
  return function () {
    var $i = $input[index];
    var el = $i.get();
    $i.removeClass('double-error');
    if (el.value != '') {
      values[el.value] = 0;
      $input.each(function() {
        if (this.value == el.value) {
          values[el.value]++;
        }
      });
    }
    if (index++ > $input.length) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      index = 0;

      // Now set elements
      intervalId = setInterval(function () {
        var $i = $input[index];
        var el = $i.get();
        if (values[el.value] > 1) {
          var name = el.value;
          var product_model = $i.parent().parent().find('.product-model').text();
          var m = product_model.toLowerCase().areplace(search,replace);
          $i.parent().find('input[type=\'text\']').val(name + '-' + m);
        }
        if (index++ > $input.length) {
          clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
      }, INTERVAL);
    }
  };
}()), INTERVAL);
```

Here, we do just a little bit of work, then use `setInterval` to release the main thread so that other work can be performed.  After `INTERVAL` we will do some more work, until we finish and call `clearInterval`

Comment: @ CaptEmulation Your code looks promising... but does not work. I can't get it to work. I can't find why...

Comment: I am sorry to hear that.  Not having a full environment I just wrote the code without being able to run or debug it.  Can you be any more specific as to what problem you are seeing?  Or maybe you can replicate your original problem in a jsfiddle?  Also I use more advanced code (that I can not share) to handle queues of actions.  You can look for a job scheduling framework.  A quick search revealed something like this https://github.com/zefer/JobQueue